# Sending Cell data to destinationViewController with prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uigesturerecognizer

I have added a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to my `UICollectionViewCell` and created a segue, so by long pressing a `cell` the user segues to a `ViewController`.

I already have an ordinary segue using the `didSelect` method to display cell details, but the secondary long press gesture segue takes the user to a action screen to delete the cell.

Unfortunately when using the `prepareForSegue` to send the cell data to the `destinationViewController` I cannot use the standard `let indexPaths = self.collectionView.indexPathForSelectedRow()` method because I am creating my own selection when using a gesture recogniser.

So how can I send the cell data to the `destinationViewController` with `prepareForSegue` using the `gestureRecognizer` ?

```
if segue.identifier == "cellAction" {
    let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! CellActionViewController

    //This will cause an 'array index out of range error 
    let indexPaths = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
    let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as! NSIndexPath

    //Here is how I would send the cell data
    let selectedCell = Items[indexPath.row]

    vc.selectedItem = selectedCell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to access the particular cell that was pressed, and use this information to obtain its index path from within `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)`.

The first thing to note is that `sender` parameter on the `prepareForSegue` method. I presume you are calling `performSegueWithIdentifier(_:sender:)` from your gesture handling function. Notice this also has a `sender` parameter, which is the same object that is passed to `prepareForSegue`. You can use this to pass your cell instance.

The second thing to note is that `UIGestureRecognizer` has a `view` property, which should most likely be the cell itself. Armed with this knowledge, you can pass the pressed cell instance to `prepareForSegue`:

```
func handleLongPress(longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if longPress.state == .Ended {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("cellAction", sender: longPress.view)
    }
}
```

Now, within `prepareForSegue` you can cast `sender` to your cell class, and get its index path using `UICollectionView`s `indexPathForCell(_:)` method:

```
override prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "cellAction" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! CellActionViewController
        if let cell = sender as? MyCell {
            let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell)
            let selectedItem = items[indexPath.row]
            vc.selectedItem = selectedItem
        } else {
            fatalError("Invalid sender, was expecting instance of MyCell.)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, you are right on how I use the gesture. Unfortunately I am still a beginner and am unsure what you mean when saying cast Sender to the cell class. I have already created a custom UICollectionViewCell class.

Comment: In `prepareForSegue`, `sender` is of type `AnyObject?` because it can be an object of any class or `nil`. You need to downcast it to `MyCell` (or whatever your cell subclass is called) using optional binding with the `as?` operator. It's this line in the last code block: `if let cell = sender as? MyCell`. You need to cast it to your cell class so the compiler knows that you're passing a `MyCell` instance to `indexPathForCell(_:)`, rather than `AnyObject?`, which would cause a compiler error.

Comment: Alright I understand, thanks for your help I really appreciate it. I like to understand the code rather than blindly copy and paste and answer (Y)